# Fantasy book series about a young male character using lightning magic trained by an old man

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, magic

The story had three schools of magic, fire, earth/healing and storm. Each was controlled by a god. Fire and storm were guys while the other was a girl. These gods could possess humans which would allow the human to wield great magic.

If I recall correctly, the main character (MC) was a young male and was taken in by an old magician for some reason and taught storm magic (we later learn that he is part of a branch of the royal family, and is the only one left alive along with his sister).

He and the old man cross a desert and find a lady who they help and bring with them. The lady sticks with them till the end. The old man is bringing our MC to his sister. This is because the land they live in is ruled by a dictator that is extremely powerful and immortal due to the use of black magic.

The only way to defeat him is to either use the power of the gods, or use a sword that can only be wielded by the royal line. The tyrant was a friend of the MC's ancestor and cursed the main branch and all side branches except a single one to steal the empire. MC's sister knew this already and came along with a bodyguard.

They are then on a quest to find the sword of light that can kill the dictator. Unfortunately they have to use that power to defend against another dark force that leaves them with only a little of the original power. The old man dies. They go to a collection of fortresses and fight against the tyrant's army of hellspawn and shadow wraiths.

In the end the MC with lightning magic, his sister with fire, and the bodyguard with earth let the gods control them as there is no other way to beat the dictator. The gods defeat the dictator but this results in them keeping what seems to be sole control of the bodies as the original souls are crushed to dust.

The lady they saved in the desert was in love with MC and curses at the gods for taking his life. In the epilogue, the gods decide to leave the bodies and the original souls are placed back in their own bodies. After this, they decide to head to the fortresses and live their own lives.

I read this like 5 years ago on Kindle and forgot the title of the book. It's a trilogy and the cover of the first book is blue with a circle containing runes and a lightning bolt while the second contains a sword. Aimed towards highschool and college people.

Answer (score 4):

Likely *Stormwielder* (2021) by Aaron Hodges, first book of the "Sword of Light" trilogy.

The official summary is very vague, but [this Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1616648222) has several matching elements:

> In a moment of panic 17 year old **Eric lost control of his magic, causing a lightning storm** that wreaked death and destruction on a village. **He finds a mentor in the shape of Alistair, a servant of the goddess**, who has been tasking with training Eric so he can properly control his magic and then use it in **the battle the gods wage against the demonic Arkon**. To complicate matters Gabriel, a villager who lost his whole family, is on Eric's trail and desperate for vengeance.

The series is titled "sword of light", which fits with the terms you used to describe the sword they were looking for.
The cover matches your recollection: blue, runic-looking shapes, lightning.

[image: blue cover with sword in a circle, surrounded by lightning]

---

Found with the Google query `fantasy book storm magic god site:goodreads.com/book`, and then switching to the "Images" tab to see if any cover matched.